# Why does this program block until someone connects to the FIFO / named pipe?

Tags: rust, pipe, named-pipes

I found [this script](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3359f7575a71a077409ba0d6b16a6098) in the post [Recommended way of IPC in Rust](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/recommended-way-of-ipc-in-rust/31116/6) where a server and client are created with named pipes.

I want to understand how it works so I started debugging. When I start the server with `cargo run listen`, the program reaches the `open` function and the following happens. I know this is a feature and not a bug, but I do not understand why it happens.

In the `main` function the `listen` function is called and then the `listen` function calls the `open` function:

```rust
use libc::{c_char, mkfifo};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::env::args;
use std::fs::{File, OpenOptions};
use std::io::{Error, Read, Result, Write};
use std::os::unix::ffi::OsStrExt;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut args = args();
    let _ = args.next();
    match args.next().as_ref().map(String::as_str) {
        Some("listen") => listen()?,
        Some("send") => {
            let msg = args.next().unwrap();
            send(msg)?;
        }
        _ => {
            eprintln!("Please either listen or send.");
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

pub struct Fifo {
    path: PathBuf,
}

impl Fifo {
    pub fn new(path: PathBuf) -> Result<Self> {
        let os_str = path.clone().into_os_string();
        let slice = os_str.as_bytes();
        let mut bytes = Vec::with_capacity(slice.len() + 1);
        bytes.extend_from_slice(slice);
        bytes.push(0); // zero terminated string
        let _ = std::fs::remove_file(&path);
        if unsafe { mkfifo((&bytes[0]) as *const u8 as *const c_char, 0o644) } != 0 {
            Err(Error::last_os_error())
        } else {
            Ok(Fifo { path })
        }
    }
    
    /// Blocks until anyone connects to this fifo.
    pub fn open(&self) -> Result<FifoHandle> {
        let mut pipe = OpenOptions::new().read(true).open(&self.path)?;

        let mut pid_bytes = [0u8; 4];
        pipe.read_exact(&mut pid_bytes)?;
        let pid = u32::from_ne_bytes(pid_bytes);

        drop(pipe);

        let read = OpenOptions::new()
            .read(true)
            .open(format!("/tmp/rust-fifo-read.{}", pid))?;

        let write = OpenOptions::new()
            .write(true)
            .open(format!("/tmp/rust-fifo-write.{}", pid))?;

        Ok(FifoHandle { read, write })
    }
}

impl Drop for Fifo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let _ = std::fs::remove_file(&self.path);
    }
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum Message {
    Print(String),
    Ack(),
}

pub struct FifoHandle {
    read: File,
    write: File,
}

impl FifoHandle {
    pub fn open<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> Result<Self> {
        let pid = std::process::id();

        let read_fifo_path = format!("/tmp/rust-fifo-write.{}", pid);
        let read_fifo = Fifo::new(read_fifo_path.into())?;

        let write_fifo_path = format!("/tmp/rust-fifo-read.{}", pid);
        let write_fifo = Fifo::new(write_fifo_path.into())?;

        let mut pipe = OpenOptions::new().write(true).open(path.as_ref())?;

        let pid_bytes: [u8; 4] = u32::to_ne_bytes(pid);
        pipe.write_all(&pid_bytes)?;
        pipe.flush()?;

        let write = OpenOptions::new().write(true).open(&write_fifo.path)?;

        let read = OpenOptions::new().read(true).open(&read_fifo.path)?;

        Ok(Self { read, write })
    }
    
    pub fn send_message(&mut self, msg: &Message) -> Result<()> {
        let msg = bincode::serialize(msg).expect("Serialization failed");
        self.write.write_all(&usize::to_ne_bytes(msg.len()))?;
        self.write.write_all(&msg[..])?;
        self.write.flush()
    }
    
    pub fn recv_message(&mut self) -> Result<Message> {
        let mut len_bytes = [0u8; std::mem::size_of::<usize>()];
        self.read.read_exact(&mut len_bytes)?;
        let len = usize::from_ne_bytes(len_bytes);

        let mut buf = vec![0; len];
        self.read.read_exact(&mut buf[..])?;

        Ok(bincode::deserialize(&buf[..]).expect("Deserialization failed"))
    }
}

fn listen() -> Result<()> {
    let fifo = Fifo::new(PathBuf::from("/tmp/rust-fifo"))?;
    loop {
        let mut handle = fifo.open()?;
        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            match handle.recv_message().expect("Failed to recieve message") {
                Message::Print(p) => println!("{}", p),
                Message::Ack() => panic!("Didn't expect Ack now."),
            }
            #[allow(deprecated)]
            std::thread::sleep_ms(1000);
            handle
                .send_message(&Message::Ack())
                .expect("Send message failed.");
        });
    }
}

fn send(s: String) -> Result<()> {
    let mut handle = FifoHandle::open("/tmp/rust-fifo")?;

    #[allow(deprecated)]
    std::thread::sleep_ms(1000);

    handle.send_message(&Message::Print(s))?;
    match handle.recv_message()? {
        Message::Print(p) => println!("{}", p),
        Message::Ack() => {}
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: You attempt to read 4 bytes from the FIFO via [`read_exact`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact). If no one has connected and sent 4 bytes, there's no data to read, so the program blocks.

Comment: oh thanks, ok i get it, but if you don't get the 4 bytes? if 2 bytes arrive? it's like maximum reads 4 bytes or specifically it has to be 4 bytes

Comment: The "exact" part of `read_exact` is important. See also [`Read::read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read).

Comment: If 2 bytes arrive, then `read_exact()` will store them into the slice and wait for the remaining 2 bytes to arrive. Once they do, it will return because the requested slice will have been filled. What do you _expect_ to happen in any of those cases?

Comment: I have been investigating and the program also freezes because when you try to open a fifo file in linux it freezes until another opens it, that's why the script freezes just when the file is opened and not when it tries to read the 4 bytes (although it also it should freeze there), am I right?